# Athena tables having history of records of every csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am uploading CSV files in the s3 bucket and creating tables through glue crawler and seeing the tables in Athena, making connection between Athena and Quicksight, and showing the result graphically there in quicksight.
But what I need to do now is keep the history of the files uploaded, instead of a new CSV file being uploaded and crawler updating the table, can I have crawler save each record separately? or is it even a reasonable thing to do? since I wonder it would then create so many tables and it'll be a mess?
I'm just trying to figure out a way to keep a history of previous records. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you run an Amazon Athena query, Athena will look at the `location` parameter defined in the table's DDL. This specifies where the data is stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Athena will **include all files in that location** when it runs the query on that table. Thus, if you wish to add more data to the table, simply add another file in that S3 location. To replace data in that table, you can **overwrite** the file(s) in that location. To delete data, you can **delete** files from that location.

There is no need to run a crawler on a regular basis. The crawler can be used to **create the table definition** and it can be run again to update the table definition if anything has changed. But you typically only need to use the crawler once to create the table definition.

If you wish to preserve historical data in the table while adding more data to the table, simply **upload the data to new files** and keep the existing data files in place. That way, any queries will include both the *historical* data and the *new* data because Athena simply looks at *all the files* in that location.